# Bootstrap 4 dynamic javascript doesnt work, works fine in Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm dynamically showing a modal using the following code:

```
// show ajax modal with content
$(document).on('click', '[data-modal]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.get($(this).data('modal'), function (data) {
        $(data).modal('show');
    });
});
```

So `data-modal` on that element would contain the URL for the AJAX call.

Now, in one of my modals, I have the following in the `modal-body` element:

```
<script>
console.log('hello world');
</script>
```

This works fine when using Bootstrap 3, as it shows `hello world` in the console after the modal is displayed. However, for whatever reason, when using Bootstrap 4 it does not work. It does not execute the script whatsoever.

What has changed between BS3 and BS4 which would cause this? Do I now have to use some type of injection library just to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out.

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('script').each(function(){
        eval($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Credit: http://subinsb.com/how-to-execute-javascript-in-ajax-response